# There is connection between Syrio Forel and Jaqen H'ghar? or between any Braavos people?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

When arya first meet Syrio Forel for sword training that time he said 
"there is only one god and his name is death."
and when arya reach Braavos and meet Jaqen H'ghar.
Jaqen reveals his face to Arya, claiming he is "no one" and said that 
"there is only one god and girl knows his name."

what is connection between these two sentence?

is there any coincidence? or he has training arya since the beginning?

and it is possible no one is dead after Jaqen H'ghar introduce. it just faceless men every where. because no one murdered or dead in front of Jaqen H'ghar.

and actual Syrio Forel is dead or not? because he said once that "what do we say to the god of death... not today."

and Syrio Forel is faceless men?

Comment: Multiple questions, several of which cannot be answered with certainty. And obviously no research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KyloRen puts it so well over on SciFi I will just quote [their answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132894/58193) here:

> ### We finally have conformation.
>
> **Syrio Forel is dead and is not Jaqen H'ghar**
>
> I was really diapointed to hear this, but we finally have confirmation that he is neither Jaqen H'ghar or still alive. Showrunners David Benioff and D.B. Weiss have confirmed this.
>
> > "I always was like, 'Oh, no, I feel like he's still alive,'" Williams
> >     told IGN. "I always had my own theory that he and Jaqen [the Faceless
> >     Man] were the same person."
> >     But when she finally ran the idea by showrunners David Benioff and
> >     D.B. Weiss, they shot it down without hesitation: Forel is dead. "I
> >     was like, 'Oh, OK," Williams said, laughing. "So that put that to bed
> >     really quickly, but I guess we can all still dream."
>
> [image]
>
> Syrio Forel alive or dead?  [Game of Thrones showrunners finally give definitive answer](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/syrio-forel-alive-or-dead-game-of-thrones-showrunners-finally-give-definitive-answer-a6983661.html)

Comment: As to why Jaqen says that Arya "knows his name", this could simply be referring the three death wishes that Jaqen gives Arya. If she is capable of listing people who should be killed, Arya should "know death". It could also be a broader statement about how many people that Arya has known (including close relatives) have died.